# plot box plots groups by categorical factor in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot individual boxplots per specimen, grouped and coloured by gender. However, the apparently logical code plots in 3 colors when I only have two genders.

Here is the dataset:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vm6bdiqmymi5jbe/methodissues.csv?dl=0

Here is the code:

```
VMT=read.csv("methodissues.csv")
ggplot(VMT, aes(x=sex,group=specimen,fill=sex, y=VMT)) +
geom_boxplot(width = 1) +
xlab("specimens")+
ylab("VMT (°C)")+
theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill='transparent', colour='black'),
     panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
     panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
     axis.title.x = element_text(colour="black"),
     axis.text.x  = element_text(angle=0, vjust=0.5,colour="black", size=14),
     axis.title.y = element_text(colour="black", size=14),
     axis.text.y  = element_text(angle=0, vjust=0.5,colour="black", size=14)
)+ 
theme(legend.justification=c(1,1), legend.position="none")
```

Comment: What do you mean by 3 colors? The boxes are all black and white...? I guess you forgot to set `aes(..., color = specimen)` right?

Comment: Nearly that, i actually forgot to set fill=sex, now it is edited and the problem is actually reproducible., but is not solved.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a "conflict of interest". You want the boxes to be grouped by `specimen` (which results in a box based on at the maximum only 4 values in `VMT`. More on that below.). At the same time, however, you want each box colored by sex, which is impossible to do in some cases (like when `specimen` is equal to `C5MT`), since there are some values in `specimen` that are related to both sexes `M` and `F`. Thats where the third color is comming from. It is simply a mixture of both colours used to color `sex`.

Possible solutions:

### 1. Fill by sex and put specimen on the x-axis

```
require(ggplot2)

 VMT=read.csv("methodissues.csv")

ggplot(VMT, aes(x = specimen, y = VMT, fill = sex)) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 1)
```

[image]

### 2. Facet by specimen

```
ggplot(VMT, aes(x = sex, fill = sex, y = VMT)) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 1) +
  facet_grid(~ specimen)
```

[image]

#### Word of caution:

I would strongly recommend to rethink what you are actually trying to say. I dont think a graph like that is suitable, since each box is only based on a maximum of 4 values which makes it pretty much meaningless (after all, you are trying to convey some sense of the distribution). Some "boxes" (like the one for `specimen = C5MT` and `sex = F` ) are even only made up of 1 value (and hence, for males it's only 3). This makes looking at the graph even more dubious.

Comment: thanks, but that does not group the boxplots by sexes, one at each side.